# indexedDb objectStore.openCursor so slow

Tags: javascript, html, indexeddb

The first time using the index query takes too long.

usage scenarios: mobile use webview.

After the data is saved into indexedDb, the first time you open the page query is extremely slow.

query code:

```js
var startTime = new Date().getTime();
var request = indexedDB.open("yfg");
request.onerror = function(event) {
 alert("Why didn't you allow my web app to use IndexedDB?!");
};
request.onsuccess = function(event) {
 var table = [];
 var db = request.result;
 var objectStore = db.transaction("table").objectStore("table");

 //objectStore.openCursor().onsuccess = function(event) {
 objectStore.openCursor(null,IDBCursor.NEXT).onsuccess = function(event) {
  var cursor = event.target.result;
  if (cursor) {
   table.push(cursor.value);
   cursor.continue();
  }else {
   //alert("No more entries!");
   console.log(table);
   var endTime = new Date().getTime();
   console.log("总耗时：",(endTime-startTime)/1000);
  }
 };
};
```

Execute on console:

The first result:
[image]

The second result:
[image]

Browser version:
[image]

The specific content of each piece of data:
[image]

This table sheet has these data:
[image]

Comment: how much data is being transferred?

Comment: Table sheet more than 1200 bars

Comment: bars? is that a new unit of measuring data? how many bytes in a bar? nevermind, just re-read the question properly and realise you're using IndexedDB

Comment: My English is bad.
Table sheet more than 1200 data.

Comment: I reorganized the question

Comment: can you check the memory increase after the first and second result?

Comment: Well, let me try

Comment: Memory size changes less than 1M.Probably 0.75M

Answer (score 0):

Try using [IDBObjectStore.prototype.getAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBObjectStore/getAll). `getAll` generates an array, similar to what you are doing, but involves fewer function calls than `openCursor` and is therefore more performant.

However, unlike `openCursor`, `getAll` may not be supported because it is a newer feature of indexedDB. The linked page shows a compatibility table but that may also be out of date.